# Libre Office bibliography short entry not showing correctly

Tags: libreoffice

Has someone had an experience with LibreOffice 4.4 (Version: 4.4.3.2) and bibliography?

- Wrote a record in bib. database (filled out most of the info, including SHORT NAME)
- Created an citation. <-- error
- Created a bib. table (showed up correctly)

The problem is the citation (in text) is not showing up as: [1], or [shortName] or anything meaningful, but as '*Bibliography entry*'.

However, if I copy-paste the text, it shows as: [1].

P.S. Every thing is updated/upgraded on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Unchecking [View] -> [Field Names] solved the problem.